# Questions which have not been properly answered

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, questions, answers

I have several questions in SO , for which I have not received a proper reply. It goes more into a discussion thread , which I am fine with, provided a get a reply. Unfortunately this has not been in the case. On the other hand, users see that I have a 33% accept rate , but its not my fault.

What should I do in this scenario.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: @Bobby . Somewhat but the post is not entirely correct. Maybe a notice can come up at the top saying "Please post a relevant answer" ( eg. similar to when user receives a new badge ) . I think this has something more to do with the users, what does the community think.

Comment: If you're getting non-answer answers then you can flag them for moderator attention. But if you are going to do that then don't do it too hastily - you don't want to drive away people who are trying to help you.

Comment: With questions [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645397/programmatically-select-files-using-c) its not surprising you're having an issue finding answers.

Answer (score 5):

In my not-so-expert opinion, the overwhelming majority of your [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102062/sujay-ghosh) appear to have perfectly valid answers, with numerous upvotes by other community members.

Just as a random example, the [answer provided by meklarian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669111/how-to-get-the-window-handle-of-the-desktop/1669157#1669157) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669111/how-to-get-the-window-handle-of-the-desktop) is about as good as you're going to get. I don't have anything more to add, or I'd have posted an answer of my own.

And questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883419/migrating-from-net-2-0-to-net-4-0) *are* discussion-type questions. I'm sort of surprised that one hasn't been closed already. The answer, of course, is to simply try to migrate the project and fix the errors you get. No one can give you a laundry list of *all* the things that might possibly go wrong. That wouldn't really be useful to anyone.

I'm not sure what other questions you think have received inadequate answers. The general rule if you're not getting good answers to your questions is to go back and edit your questions to *improve* them. Provide more details, try to give a better explanation of what your problem is, and add whatever new information you can think of. This also "bumps" the question back to the top of the list, so that more people will see it again. It may sound harsh, but the Stack Overflow community is pretty awesome, and usually **when you aren't getting good answers, it's because you're not asking good questions.**

On the other hand, I wouldn't worry *too* much about your accept rate. The only users whose accept rate I ever comment about are those with a 0% accept rate that are obviously new to the site, and might not even know about accepting answers. You've obviously figured out how to do that, so it's your prerogative whether you want to accept them or not. In my experience, there's little to be lost in not receiving answers from the people who, as a matter of policy, refuse to answer questions from users with a low accept rate.

Comment: "The answer, of course, is to simply try to migrate the project and fix the errors you get" . I use either Notepad++ / Slickedit to code for small projects. I developed the add method in .NET 2.0. Now I want to make the add method take optional parameters ( I have installed the .NET 4.0 on my PC ) . Would you mind sharing how would you migrate.

Comment: @Sujay: That's something that belongs in an update to that original question. "The answers I've gotten so far haven't been very helpful, as I don't develop in Visual Studio. Instead, my workflow consists of... blah blah blah". Then myself and some others might have some useful comments.